# Cloudfront Distribution With s3 bucket Images Load From Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an image website that loads images from s3 bucket. my Website Link-https://yourpng.com/

[image: See This ScreenShot]
You can see the URL of the images, I want my images to be loaded from the subdomain, https://png.yourpng.com/

To load the images from the subdomain, I insisted on using the s3 buckets with cloudfront as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: cloudfrontt]

Even after adding a subdomain to cloudfront, my images are not loading from the subdomain.

And one thing you will say is that by going to route 53, I will alias the CloudFront but my website is hosted in another hosting.

Comment: You need to change your reference to the images in your website.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image website thats loading from a domain, then your image website needs to refer to the new domain instead.

CloudFront will not redirect (without a Lambda@Edge function) to another domain

Comment: see- https://prnt.sc/sed1j3

i already make CloudFront distribution for s3 bucket, And I have also added costume subdomain, even then the URL of s 3 bucket images is not changing.

My Website- https://yourpng.com/photo/2141/picsart-eye-lens-png-download-2

also see this - https://yrpng.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/preview/picsart-eye-lens-png-download-2-11587478918ycq7argari.jpg